# Does windows azure support only asp.net mvc applications?

Tags: azure

I have a doubt about windows azure. Whether it supports only mvc applications or any type of applications developed in visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just for MVC apps. Anything that runs on Windows can run on Windows Azure. ASP.NET, PHP, Java, Node.js, etc. See https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/overview/ for lots of information.

Comment: Hi smarx. Thanks. Yesterday only i just reviewed your blog. Its nice to catch you here.